# Restoring a Trained Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have an RNN with LSTMs that uses two placeholders to train an input vector against a target vector. Training works but when restoring what do I provide the target placeholder?

Conceptually I do not understand why this needs to be done as in a production environment I would only have the input vector and would want the trained model to provide the output.

Comment: Can you post some code and the error? It will help make it clear what you are asking specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you are doing supervised learning, you have an input x and ground truth y. Your model with its parametrization provides a prediction y_hat. Through the use of an optimizer that minimizes a loss - a measure of how close your prediction is to ground truth - you adapt your model to the data and improve the results.

When you have finished training, you don't need the placeholder for y anymore as you input some x into the model and get its prediction y_hat. Therefore, you are right that you do something like

```
# load model
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('x:0')
y_hat = graph.get_tensor_by_name('whateverOutput:0')

sess.run(y_hat, feed_dict={x:myProductionData})
```

So your results are now stored in y_hat.

Comment: Yes but the restoration fails with error “must feed value for placeholder”

Comment: If you do understand the concept, why don't you post your code? You wrote that you have problems with the concept.